# <param> under <foreach> doesn't support nested fileset element

Tags: java, ant, ant-contrib

I am trying to perform a task that is supposed to iterate over a set of files. For that I am using the `foreach` task from **ant-contrib-0.3.jar**. The problem is that I am trying to pass (as param) to the target not the file path, but the file directory path.

Here is the project:

```
<project basedir="../../../" name="do-report" default="copy-all-unzipped">
    <xmlproperty keeproot="false" file="implementation/xml/ant/text-odt-properties.xml"/>
    <!--    -->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${path.infrastructure}/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <!--    -->
    <target name="copy-all-unzipped">
        <foreach target="copy-unzipped">
            <param name="file-path">
                <fileset dir="${path.unzipped}">
                    <include name="**/content.xml"/>
                </fileset>
            </param>
        </foreach>
    </target>
    <!--    -->
    <target name="copy-unzipped">
        <echo>${file-path}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```

Running the script I am getting the following message:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Users\rmrd001\git\xslt-framework\implementation\xml\ant\text-odt-build.xml:13: param doesn't support the nested "fileset" element.

I can read in several places on the internet (such as [axis.apache.org](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/foreach.html)) that `param` can have a nested `fileset` element.

Comment: Have you considered spelling it correctly?

Comment: @EJP yesterday
English is not my nature language. I entirely rely on the editor spell check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example of `<foreach>` you link to is from the [Apache Axis 1.x Ant tasks](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/foreach.html) project. This is a different `<foreach>` than the one from the [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) project.

As manouti says, the Ant-Contrib `<foreach>` doesn't support nested `param` elements. Instead, the `id` of a `<fileset>` can be passed to the `<target>` and the `<target>` can reference the `id`.

Or, you can use Ant-Contrib's [`<for>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) (not "`<foreach>`") which can call a [`<macrodef>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html)...

```
<target name="copy-all-unzipped">
    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${path.unzipped}">
                <include name="**/content.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <copy-unzipped file-path="@{file}"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>

<macrodef name="copy-unzipped">
    <attribute name="file-path"/>
    <sequential>
        <echo>@{file-path}</echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html for how to use `foreach`. The `param` must be an **attribute** not a nested element:

```
<target name="copy-all-unzipped">
    <foreach target="copy-unzipped" param="file-path">
        <fileset dir="${path.unzipped}">
            <include name="**/content.xml"/>
        </fileset>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

**EDIT:**

Since the nested fileset element is deprecated, you can replace it with a path element (haven't tried it, long time since I've used Ant...):

```
<target name="copy-all-unzipped">
    <foreach target="copy-unzipped" param="file-path">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${path.unzipped}">
               <include name="**/content.xml"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </foreach>
</target>
```

Comment: I'm getting this using the above syntax:

  [foreach] The nested fileset element is deprectated, use a nested path instead

Comment: @JohnCarlson I adapted the answer; please note I haven't tried the new code, but the [documentation of foreach](https://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) should help more. Also I suspect the deprecation message is just a warning.

Comment: That looks like the patch I've already done.  Great!  I've updated the chosen answer, apologies!